# Background color of the react application is not applied correclty

Tags: html, css, reactjs, web-applications

I trying to add the background color for my react app. background color is not applied to the whole screen.
Here is the code for the `App.js` file

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <body className="App">
      <div>
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
      </div>
    </body>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and the source code of the App.css file is here

```
.App {
  background-color: #efeff6;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
```

The result of this here and you can see some white space in left and the right sides.
[image]

Can I know that is the mistake I have done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in file index.css change this.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
html, body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```